# How can I load an image url that's in an array variable with php?

Tags: php, html

I'm loading image urls from the database using php. Here's how the data gets loaded:

```
        <?php

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $i++;
 $this->resultSet[$i] = $row[1] . " " . "<br />" . $row[2] . " " . "<br />" . " " . $row[3] . " " . "<br />" . $row[4] . " " . "<br />" . $row[5] . "<br />";
 $this->gameUrl = $row[5];
 }
```

In a foreach loop I want to load the url after each iteration.  If I put the array variable outside of the image tag it shows the url so I know that it's being accessed ok.  My problem is the formatting of the image tag.  I tried this:

```
 "<img src=\"$gameImageUrl\"/>"
```

...and it shows only the last image which means that my problem is in attaching the bracket at the end.  When I try this:

```
 "<img src=\"$gameImageUrl[$i]\"/>"
```

..nothing loads.  Finally I tried hardcoding just putting a number in the barcket like this:

```
"<img src=\"$gameImageUrl[2]\"/>"
```

and nothing returns.  My code is listed below.  Can someone please explain how to format the image tag with an array variable? Thank you so much for any help.

```
 <?php
 $QueryResult = new GameInfo();
 $searchResult = $QueryResult->getGames();
 $gameImageUrl = $QueryResult->getGameImageUrl();

 if ($searchResult)
 {
 $i = 0;
 echo<ul class='result'>";
 foreach($searchResult as $returnedResult)
    {
    $i++;
    echo "<a href='#'id='game_a_1'>GAME" . " $i" . "<div id='divGame12' class='fluid        '>" . "<img src=\"$gameImageUrl[$i]\"/>" . "       </div>" . "<div id='divGame12A' class='fluid '>" . "<p id='P_game12'>" . "$gameImageUrl[$i]" . "$returnedResult" . "</p>" . " </div>" . "</a>";
    }

 echo "</ul>";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "<p>Sorry!  Something went wrong</p>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues of concatenation and enclosure. Try this:

```
$QueryResult = new GameInfo();
$searchResult = $QueryResult->getGames();
$gameImageUrl = $QueryResult->getGameImageUrl();

if ($searchResult)
 {
 $i = 0;
 echo '<ul class="result">';

 foreach($searchResult as $returnedResult)
    {
    $i++;
    echo
      '<a href="#" id="game_a_1">GAME '.$i.'
          <div id="divGame12" class="fluid"><img src="'.$gameImageUrl[$i].'"/></div>
            <div id="divGame12A" class="fluid">
               <p id="P_game12">'.$gameImageUrl[$i].' '.$returnedResult.'</p>
           </div>
       </a>';
    }

 echo "</ul>";
 }
 else
 {
  echo "<p>Sorry!  Something went wrong</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to enclose your variable like:

```
"<img src=\"${gameImageUrl[$i]}\"/>"
```

Notice the ${variable}

Answer (score -1):

oh god, ok please can you first clean up your code to help us clarify where the issue might be. the reason why this might be happening is because you are echo'ing the img url instead of first assigning to a variable from you database to concatenate  this into the echo iteration. example echo ''. $rs['photo'] .''. the $rs variable should be connected to your database.